Send email using existing draft email using Gmail API
Actually I am having multiple emails as List and one by one want to send emails using Gmail API. In my case I want to use existing draft email from Gmail Draft Folder and want to send it. The following code is getting executed when I specify the Receiver's email id (To) in the draft email, but without Receiver's email id I am unable to send email.
I tried service.users().drafts().send(userId=user_email, body={'id': message_id}).execute() which takes specific email from Gmail Draft Folder based on the message_id but I want to use same draft email and want to send it to the various email ids, for which I write following code.
Can anyone please help me in altering code so that each time the draft will remain same and I can send it to multiple email ids one by one?
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose']

def get_credentials():
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credential.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds

creds = get_credentials()
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

user_email = 'me'

drafts = service.users().drafts().list(userId=user_email).execute()




What have you tried? You have a list of drafts, sure, but where is the code where you split those into separate drafts and you trying to alter them?
